# Browser freezes when use function api in ng-if AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-if

I use angularjs and I have a problem with `ng-if` when I use a function that returns `true` or `false` in two API, the browser is freezes

```
self.isShow= function() {
    service.getKioskLogByKioskId([stateParams.kioskId], function (data) {
        self.kioskLog = data;
        service.getKiosk([stateParams.kioskId], function (kiosk) {
            self.kiosk = kiosk;
            debugger 
            if (self.kioskLog.isConnected && self.kiosk.isActive)

                return true;
            else
                return false;

        });
    });
}
```

and in html

```
ng-if="self.isShow()"
```

Comment: Why you have `debugger` statement? That will surely get your browser stuck in debug mode.

Answer (score 7):

Angular's `ng-if` can't be an async, it expects to get `true/false` in synchronous manner.

Don't forget that **EVERY** angular directive creates a "watch" that will be invoked as part of angular's dirty check mechanism, If you make a "heavy" operation on it, it will stuck the browser.

Basically there are 2 wrong things in your code, the first one, your `isShow` is not returning boolean value at all, (it always returns undefined).
The second one, you are probably making an API call inside the `service.getKioskLogByKioskId` method.

In order to solve both of the issues, you can make the `service.getKioskLogByKioskId` call inside the constructor of you controller, (if it is a component there is [`$onInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) lifecycle hook for that), then save the async result on the controller, and use it the view.

It should look something like that:

```
class MyController {
  constructor(stateParams) {
    this.stateParams = stateParams;
    this.isShow = false; // initial value
  }

  $onInit() {
     const self =this;
     service.getKiosk([stateParams.kioskId], function (kiosk) {
          self.kiosk = kiosk;
          debugger 
          if (self.kioskLog.isConnected && self.kiosk.isActive)
              self.isShow = true;
          else
              self.isShow = false;

     });
  }
}


// view.html
<div ng-if="$ctrl.isShow"></div>
```